# How to find all occurrences of a certain variable/method in Eclipse? i.e the equivalent of "cmd + b" of Android Studio

Tags: java, eclipse

Say, we have a constant class:

```
public class Constant {
    ...
    public static final String UNIVERSAL_VARIABLE = "many classes will find me handy";

}
```

In AndroidStudio, if I hover to UNIVERSAL_VARIABLE and click `cmd + b`, then it will show all classes where UNIVERSAL_VARIABLE are used, and on which line.

How do we do this in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CTRL + SHIFT + G
```

Or right click, References -> Workspace (or Project).

Comment: Awesome! On Mac, it's `CMD + SHIFT + G`.